# OpenGL using a logarithmic coordinates axis

Tags: opengl

Does OpenGL support custom (logarithmic in my case) coordinates space ?
I would need to display some raw data and ideally have a Y logarithmic axis. The purpose being not to alter those data and let the GPU do most of the job.

Comment: you could do what you want in a shader.

Comment: that is an option I thought about

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the data is dynamic, the GPU would be your best bet.

Simply transform the coordinates in your vertex shader using the glsl `log()`.

If you need log10, use

```
log10(x) = log(x) / log(10) = (1 / log(10)) * log(x)
```

Make sure to precalc `1 / log(10)`.

In a naive implementation, any color shading in the fragment shader will be linear over pixels (i.e. exponential over source data)... This is the common visual representation in a logarithmic diagram, so you probably don't need to worry about this.

Comment: Ok I will then go ahead with a shader. Thanks